# Where is the location of the Nautilus file manager icon in Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: unity, nautilus, icons

I successfully changed several icons by adding .png files into the *pixmaps* folder, and editing the programs' *Icon=*.

Nautilus doesn't seem to follow that rule, and I am curious where does it pull its icons from, and how can I find out? It also has 3 nautilus Files files in usr/share/applications, and even more on the console list. Is it enough to just change the nautilus.desktop file, or will I have to change more?

Answer (score 1):

**Nautilus** is a GNOME file manager and using sudo allows for root access to otherwise locked folders due to permission error in Ubuntu.

In *Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS,* the Nautilus icon is located here: `/usr/share/icons/Humanity/apps/128/system-file-manager.svg`

The smaller version of Nautilus icon is located in other folders, such as `/apps/32/system-file-manager.svg`

Another version of Nautilus icon (i.e. gastropod seashell) can be saved from here:  `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/32/Nautilus_icon.svg/120px-Nautilus_icon.svg.png`

The `Nautilus.desktop` file looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Version=3.14.3
Name=GNOME Nautilus
GenericName=File Manager
Comment=Access Folders as Root
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Humanity/apps/128/system-file-manager.svg
Exec=gksudo nautilus /home
Terminal=false
Name[en_US]=Nautilus
```

Make sure to change `Permissions` tab, `Owner:` and `Group:` set to `Read and Write`, and check box for `Execute: Allow executing file as program`